# Firefox Plugin Downloading

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, firebug1.5

I am trying to create a SIMPLE plugin, no interface is necessary, that will automatically download and save to "Desktop/MyFolder/" everything that the page loads.  My thought was to make an extension that extends FireBug, but that seems to be rather challenging.  I got it to do some things, however on things like images, flv's, and mp3s the content appears to be placed in the file, however when I try to view them they are not viewable/invalid formats.

I am thinking I need to just need to do some kind of MimeType or file format thing.  It really looks good, however something is obviously missing.

Thanks in advance!

```
FBL.ns(function() { with (FBL) { 

const Cc = Components.classes;
const Ci = Components.interfaces;

const dirService = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Ci.nsIProperties);

// ************************************************************************************************
// Module implementation

Firebug.EverythingExportModule = extend(Firebug.Module,
{
    initialize: function(owner)
    {
        Firebug.Module.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        // Register NetMonitor listener
        this.netListener = new EverythingExport();
        Firebug.NetMonitor.addListener(this.netListener);
    },

    shutdown: function()
    {
        Firebug.Module.shutdown.apply(this, arguments);

        // Unregister NetMonitor listener
        Firebug.NetMonitor.removeListener(this.netListener);
        this.netListener.outputStream.close();
    }
});

// ************************************************************************************************
// Net Panel Listener

function EverythingExport(outputStream)
{
    // Get unique file within user profile directory. 
    var file = dirService.get("ProfD", Ci.nsIFile);
    file.append("netlistener");
    file.append("netMonitor.txt");
    file.createUnique(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);

    // Initialize output stream.
    this.outputStream =
        Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
        .createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);

    // write, create, truncate
    this.outputStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
}

EverythingExport.prototype = 
{
    onRequest: function(context, file)
    {
        if (FBTrace.DBG_NETLISTENER)
            FBTrace.sysout("netListener.onResponse; " + (file ? file.href : ""));
    },

    onExamineResponse: function(context, request)
    {
        if (FBTrace.DBG_NETLISTENER)
            FBTrace.sysout("netListener.onExamineResponse;" + request.name);
    },

    onResponse: function(context, file)
    {
        return;
        if (FBTrace.DBG_NETLISTENER)
            FBTrace.sysout("netListener.onResponse; " + (file ? file.href : ""));

        try
        {
            var text = file.href + " (" + formatTime
                (file.endTime - file.startTime) + ")\n";
            this.outputStream.write(text, text.length);
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            if (FBTrace.DBG_NETLISTENER || FBTRace.DBG_ERRORS)
                FBTrace.sysout("netListener.onResponse; EXCEPTION", err);
        }
    },

    onResponseBody: function(context, file)
    {

        Firebug.Console.openGroup("EverythingDownloader", null, "group", null, false);
        Firebug.Console.log("Found File");
        Firebug.Console.log(file);
        Firebug.Console.log(context);
        Firebug.Console.log(this.transport);
        Firebug.Console.log(this);
        Firebug.Console.log(file.mimeType);
        savefile="C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Desktop\\MyFolder\\" + file.startTime + "-music.mp3";
        //Yes I know that is not cross-platform friendly...
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                Firebug.Console.log(req);
                try {
                    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("Permission to save file was denied.");
                }
                var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
                file.initWithPath( savefile );
                if ( file.exists() == false ) {
                    Firebug.Console.log( "Creating file... " );
                    file.create( Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420 );
                }
                var outputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
                    .createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream );
                /* Open flags 
                #define PR_RDONLY       0x01
                #define PR_WRONLY       0x02
                #define PR_RDWR         0x04
                #define PR_CREATE_FILE  0x08
                #define PR_APPEND      0x10
                #define PR_TRUNCATE     0x20
                #define PR_SYNC         0x40
                #define PR_EXCL         0x80
                */
                /*
                ** File modes ....
                **
                ** CAVEAT: 'mode' is currently only applicable on UNIX platforms.
                ** The 'mode' argument may be ignored by PR_Open on other platforms.
                **
                **   00400   Read by owner.
                **   00200   Write by owner.
                **   00100   Execute (search if a directory) by owner.
                **   00040   Read by group.
                **   00020   Write by group.
                **   00010   Execute by group.
                **   00004   Read by others.
                **   00002   Write by others
                **   00001   Execute by others.
                **
                */
                outputStream.init( file, 0x04 | 0x08 | 0x20, 420, 0 );
                var result = outputStream.write( this.responseText, this.responseText.length );
                Firebug.Console.log("Done!");
                outputStream.close();
                Firebug.Console.closeGroup();
            }
        }

        req.open("GET", file.href, true);
        req.send(null);
        return;
        if (FBTrace.DBG_NETLISTENER)
            FBTrace.sysout("netListener.onResponseBody; " + (file ? file.href : ""), file);
        //Firebug.Console.log(file);
        //
    }
};

var savefile="";
// ************************************************************************************************
// Registration

Firebug.registerModule(Firebug.EverythingExportModule);

// ************************************************************************************************
}});
```

Comment: You'll probably get more and better responses if you describe briefly what you've already tried (which is different than posting the entirety of your source code) and what is or isn't working.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fire the "Save page as" from Firefox? Monitor the page load, then call the firefox action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, well I could not figre that out, so all I did was have a  C# program do a FileSystem Watch (Google it) and when it saw a file within the filesize bounds I was looking for, it copied and renamed it to where I needed.  It isn't a FireBug plugin, but it did work.

Comment: (UPDATE) Another plugin that helps with this is called BetterCache (a firefox plugin).  For whatever reason wil will *NOT* find it on google, you gotta do a good bit of digging right on the firefox plugins website.  If you have problems finding it, let me know.